# Best way to 'inherit' from other components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, oop, react-native

For example, if I needed to make a "small" and a "large" version of a button that had a lot of (but not all) methods & state in common, what would be the best way to implement this in React Native?

The issue I have with simply extending the "parent" component (I may be wrong about this) is that working with Props has been messy.

The way I've been implementing it has simply been to give the "parent" component a boolean prop (in this example, to represent "small" or "large") and then changing its features based on that boolean's value. The "child" components are pretty much only there for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Just extends your component to make a child component.

```
class Label extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className='plain-label';
  }
   render(){
     return <span className={this.className}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}


class SmallLabel extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className = this.className + ' small-label';
  }
}
```

Then use it:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
      ....
      <Label> Plain Label </Label>
      <SmallLabel> SmallLabel </SmallLabel>
    }
}
```

Inheritance is in most scenarios — just not good a viable solution. Because extending components with inheritance more or less leads to a scenario at some point, where the behaviors cannot be clubbed seamlessly. However, with Composition, its possible.

Good practice for extending/subclassing React Component, See: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/best-practices-for-extending-subclassing-components/1820/3

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to override any methods and just going to make visual changes it is better to use props. Creating different components just for visual changes can create unnecessary complicated logic.

What you can do is to get use of [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)

**Example**

```
class CustomLabel extends React.Component{
   render(){
     const { isSmall, containerStyle, children } = this.props; 
     return (
       <span
         className={`plain-label ${(isSmall && 'small-label')}`}
         style={containerStyle}
       >
         {children} 
       </span>
     )
   }
}

CustomLabel.defaultProps = {
  isSmall: false,
  containerStyle: {},
  children: 'I need some children to display'
};

export default CustomLabel;
```

---

```
<CutomLabel>{'Plain label because gets the default props'}</CustomLabel>
<CustomLabel isSmall>{'Small label because prop is true'}</CustomLabel>
<CustomLabel isSmall containerStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>{'Red small label'}</CustomLabel>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the sizing goes I would recommend just passing the classname to the component, and having css styling conditional upon that classname (if you are using external stylesheets). As far as extending the class goes its hard to give an accurate answer without knowing your exact use-case.